# install libdrm_2.4.60 to debian wheezy

Tags: linux, debian

I am attempting to install mesa 10 to a linux debian wheezy on an ivy bridge computer. To do so i need to update libdrm.

I followed these instructions:
http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/x/libdrm.html

I have successfully built the package but checkinstall fails with the following error:

```
(Reading database ... 201946 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking libdrm (from .../libdrm_2.4.60-1_amd64.deb) ...
dpkg: error processing /home/dapper/Downloads/libdrm/libdrm-2.4.60/libdrm_2.4.60-1_amd64.deb (--install):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/include/xf86drmMode.h', which is also in package libdrm-dev 2.4.40-1~deb7u2
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /home/dapper/Downloads/libdrm/libdrm-2.4.60/libdrm_2.4.60-1_amd64.deb
/var/tmp/tmp.PmSU0v8QiA/dpkginstall.log
```

I am not totally new to linux, but I'm not sure how to get around this issue.

Comment: Don't use checkinstall. If you want a newer version of libdrm, backport a newer Debian package. If you want more details, ping me (prefix my user name with the @ symbol).

Comment: yep...So in the end I did this:

add experimental to my source list
then:
apt-get update
apt-get -t experimental install libdrm-dev

now if i could only install mesa correctly...

Comment: Actually, you should rebuild it on your computer.